# DocumentFile.fromFile on 5.0+

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

In my testing I'm finding that any `DocumentFile` created with `fromFile` fails any write (`createFile`, `createDirectory`, etc) on 5.0+ even if you have permission to the root from the SAF.

Is this expected behavior?

If `fromFile` is ONLY for <5.0 compatibility I really wish they would have been clear on that in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `fromFile` generates a `RawDocumentFile`, which appears to simply wrap a file.  I don't see how this would offer any additional write permission that the `File` itself would not have, regardless of SAF permission, so I'm going to say that `fromFile` should act solely as a backwards compatibility (<4.4) factory.  I've submitted an enhancement request to update the documentation to explain this.

Comment: Hi, have you found a way around it yet ? I don't want to rewrite my whole application just for this. using DocumentFile.fromFile seemed acceptable but didn't work for me either.

Comment: It doesn't work because you can't interact with `File` any longer.  It's a helper for apps that bridge 5.0. You can take a look at a library I wrote to simplify interacting with the $h!+ access framework, but I never finished it because I created a 5.0+ app for other reasons.

https://github.com/rcketscientist/DocumentActivity
If you don't want to use `DocumentActivity` which helps resume tasks after req. permission which is a UX nightmare you can still use:

https://github.com/rcketscientist/DocumentActivity/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/anthonymandra/framework/DocumentUtil.java

Answer (score 0):

**If you dont want to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE or ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to get an Uri**, you can convert FILE to Uri (SAF) using the following method valid from API19(Android4.4-Kitkat) to API28(Android8-Oreo):

```
 /**
 * Ing.N.Nyerges 2019 V2.0
 *
 * Storage Access Framework(SAF) Uri's creator from File (java.IO),
 * for removable external storages
 *
 * @param context Application Context
 * @param file File path + file name
 * @return Uri[]:
 *   uri[0] = SAF TREE Uri
 *   uri[1] = SAF DOCUMENT Uri
 */
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static Uri[] getSafUris (Context context, File file) {

    Uri[] uri = new Uri[2];
    String scheme = "content";
    String authority = "com.android.externalstorage.documents";

    // Separate each element of the File path
    // File format: "/storage/XXXX-XXXX/sub-folder1/sub-folder2..../filename"
    // (XXXX-XXXX is external removable number
    String[] ele = file.getPath().split(File.separator);
    //  ele[0] = not used (empty)
    //  ele[1] = not used (storage name)
    //  ele[2] = storage number
    //  ele[3 to (n-1)] = folders
    //  ele[n] = file name

    // Construct folders strings using SAF format
    StringBuilder folders = new StringBuilder();
    if (ele.length > 4) {
        folders.append(ele[3]);
        for (int i = 4; i < ele.length - 1; ++i) folders.append("%2F").append(ele[i]);
    }

    String common = ele[2] + "%3A" + folders.toString();

    // Construct TREE Uri
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.scheme(scheme);
    builder.authority(authority);
    builder.encodedPath("/tree/" + common);
    uri[0] = builder.build();

    // Construct DOCUMENT Uri
    builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.scheme(scheme);
    builder.authority(authority);
    if (ele.length > 4) common = common + "%2F";
    builder.encodedPath("/document/" + common + file.getName());
    uri[1] = builder.build();

    return uri;
}
```